# Accessing child class in Table per Hierarchy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class EsBase
{
    [Key, Required]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)] 
    public bool SoftDelete { get; set; }
}

public class User: EsBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<Role> RolesRequested { get; set; } 
}

public class Scorer: User
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to work with Scorer db objects I get an error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.User_6F1B1...' type to the 'Data.Models.Scorer' type is not valid.

I guess this is because the db table stores both Users and Scorers so I can't just add a new Scorer.

User may get Scorer class/status after User has already been created.

How to set this up in code so I can add Scorer properties to a User?

Comment: `var scorer = new Scorer(myUser);` ? Maybe you need to add constructors? Edit: the `User` that's created is fetched from db? Is it just created with `new` keyword? Make sure it's attached to db

Comment: Can you post the code where you try to interact with the Scorer?